# Permission denied when using matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook

Trying to make an animation using example code found [here](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/animation/animate_decay.html). I have installed both `ffmpeg` and `yasm`, but when I run the code, including the line

```
ani.save('test.mp4', writer = FFwriter, dpi = 40)
```

I get the following error.

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

(where `FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps = 30)` is defined in the beginning of my Jupyter doc). I have tried so much, but can't get anything to work. Even tried changing the permissions of `ffmpeg` but still can't get the error to go away.

**EDIT**
Here is my imports and such to include more detail

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/'
FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps = 30)
```

Comment: Have you tried running the script as sudo so that you have permissions?

Comment: the issue is caused by where you're trying to save the file to. You likely need to provide a full path to somewhere you have permission so save the file.

Comment: @Cfreak I tried providing the path to my desktop and still didn't work.

Comment: @Michael by that I assume you mean running `sudo python /Users/pathtofile/filename.py`? If yes, then I did try this and still got the error.

Comment: In my case I fixed the same problem by changing the file name to `os.getcwd() + "/fname"`, changing the whole directory to not include any non-decodable characters (I.E Hebrew characters), and pressing allow when my antivirus tried to block the writer after performing the two previous steps.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have permission to save in your working directory. Either write a full filepath to a place where you do have permission or run your script with sudo so that you do have permission.

Comment: Using `/Users/natestemen/Desktop/test.mp4` I still get the same error.

Comment: Try running your script or interpreter with sudo

Comment: I did try running `sudo python *path to file*` and still got the same error!

Comment: Even when saving to desktop?

Comment: Yes. Could it be something with python not having access to ffmpeg properly?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was solved by installing `imagemagick`. If you use `conda`:

```
conda install -c conda-forge imagemagick
```